# iPhone applications internal audio recording

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tomcat, audio

I want to record audio that is played by my application in a file. does somebody have any idea to do that? it is also achieved in talking tomcat application.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to record and play an audio file on an iPhone:

- You could use the standard `Core Audio` Framework which is provided in Objective-C and C Code.
- Or what probably would be easier is using the only in IOS available `AVAudio*` Classes.

Have a look at the AVAudioRecorder class. Its pretty simple to use and if you google for this class name you will find plenty of example code:
[API - AVAudioRecorder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: this is not what I need. I want to record a sound in a file while this same sound is playing.